# Solution to $u_x + y u_y = -u$ with $u(0, y) = \cos y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am studying for my PDEs test and I want to make sure I can solve this type of equations.

I used the method of characteristics.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{b}{a} = y$$

Integrating I get
$$C = ye^{-x}$$
where $C$ is a constant.

I can make the substitutions
$$\xi = x$$
$$\eta = ye^{-x}$$
$$u(x,y) = w(\xi,\eta)$$

Substituting in the PDE, in terms of $w, \eta, \xi$ it becomes
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}\xi} + w = 0$$

I used the Integrating factor method to solve this ODE, which gives

$$w = f(\eta) e ^{-\xi}$$

If we substitute back to $u, x, y$ this becomes

$$w(\xi,\eta)=u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x})e^{-x}$$
The initial conditions give
$$u(0,y)=\cos y =f(y)$$

Thus, the final solution is
$$u(x,y) = \cos (ye^{-x})e^{-x}$$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 looks correct to me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check whether it satisfies your PDE. With $u(x,y)=\cos(ye^{-x})e^{-x}$ you get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)+y\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u(x,y)= -e^{-x}\cos(ye^{-x})e^{-x}=-u(x,y)$$ and also $$u(0,y)=\cos(y).$$
Thus YES, your result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct

$$u_x + y u_y = -u$$
$$u_x + y u_y +u=0$$
$$u_x + \frac {\partial}{\partial_y}(yu)=0$$
$$\frac 1 y\frac {\partial}{\partial_x}(yu) + \frac {\partial}{\partial_y}(yu)=0$$
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial_x}(yu) +y \frac {\partial}{\partial_y}(yu)=0$$
We have that $uy=c_2$
$$\frac {dx}1=\frac {dy}y \implies c_1=\frac {e^x}y$$
$$uy=f(\frac {e^x}y)$$
$$u(x,y)=\frac 1 y f(\frac {e^x}y)$$
$$u(0,y)=\frac {f(1/y)}y  \implies f(y)=\frac {\cos (1/y) }y$$
Therefore
$$u(x,y)=e^{-x}\cos (ye^{-x})$$